# Iterate through objects to draw on panel

Tags: java, jpanel, paintcomponent, repaint

I'm a little stump on getting a jump start on this assignment. Any help is appreciated. I have a class called MapView and it's essentially the window of where the game is going to be drawn on the panel. I currently have it iterating through the other classes/objects under the `update` method already. What would be the best way to iterate through the objects again to draw the game objects? I'm not sure what to do. I have draw methods under each object class also but trying to figure out how to draw those also and draw it through the iterator.

```
public class MapView extends JPanel implements IObserver, ActionListener{
    JPanel myPanel;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);
    int x = 0;
    int moveX = 2;
    public MapView(){
        super.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Map:"));
        myPanel = new JPanel();
    }
    public void update(IObservable o, Object arg){
        GameWorldProxy gwp = (GameWorldProxy) o;
        Iterator gameObjects = gwp.getCollection().getIterator();
        while(gameObjects.hasNext()){
            GameObject gameObj = (GameObject) gameObjects.getNext();
            System.out.println(gameObj);
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        repaint();
    }
}
```

How do I grab the current objects and iterate through them to draw it correctly on the panel?

Comment: GameObject have draw method right?

Comment: No it doesn't, should it? All the objects that are put into GameObject does though

Comment: Best design would be every GameObject care about the draw of itself and then the world call the draw of world-objects

Comment: As in each class object has its own draw method? For example I need a car in the game, the `Car` class has a `draw()` method and I could call it in `MapView` with `paintCar.draw()` ? How would I iterate through the objects successfully drawing each one?

Comment: Car extends GameObject right? GameObject should have draw() method and every subclass should override it to draw it (example the car override draw and in the class this method draw the car)

Comment: Yes, Car extends another class and that class extends GameObject so essentially the same thing. Ok I think I get it. Correct me if I'm wrong but basically when it iterate through the objects it'll call GameObject's `draw()` method and that method should draw the right shape according to what is in the list? Do I need to have another iterator in `paintComponent()` ?